# SQL Procedure to get most repeated values

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have the following tables:

```
table Guy{
  ID integer PK,
  Country varchar(50)
}
table Activity{
  id_Act integer PK,
  Guy_ID FK,
  Date_Act date
}
```

They have a relation of one to may (guy to Activity). Also, this tables are made-up so sorry me if there are mistakes.

Now, I want to know wich years had the most activities done by guys from country "XPTO" using a procedure.

What is the best option here? (using Oracle SQL, PL SQL).

EDIT:

I started with this query to get the repetead values counted. After this step I don't know what to do.

```
 Select to_char(A.Date_Act, 'YYYY'), count(to_char(A.Date_Act, 'YYYY')) AS conter
 from GUY G, ACTIVITY A
 where G.ID = A.GUY_ID AND G.COUNTRY = 'XPTO'
 GROUP BY A.Date_Act;
```

Comment: And why not a simple query? You only need to use `count()` and `group by`, and `order by count(something) desc`

Comment: It is ask to do a procedure but that is not the problem here. My problem is to get the final table (and the query to get it)

Comment: With the ideas provided in my previous comment, try to write the query. If it works, put it inside a procedure. If it doesn't, please edit your question and include your attempted solution and describe why it's not working

Comment: Edited... That code is not entirely correct. Gives an error in group by but I don't know how to fix it either.

Comment: Why do you use pseudo-code? Life is hard enough without it!

Comment: The choice between Oracle SQL and PL/SQL could also be stated like this : do you just want to display the result of a query, or do you want to do additional coding/functionality, on the result of that query ? For the first, Oracle SQL is just fine. The other is PL/SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You need to group by the function:

```
Select to_char(A.Date_Act, 'YYYY'), count(A.id_Act) AS conter
from GUY G join ACTIVITY A on G.ID = A.GUY_ID
where G.COUNTRY = 'XPTO'
GROUP BY to_char(A.Date_Act, 'YYYY');
```

To get the years with the max number of activities you can use analytic functions:

```
select yr, conter from
    (Select to_char(A.Date_Act, 'YYYY') AS yr, count(A.id_Act) AS conter,
           rank() over (order by count(A.id_Act) desc) rnk
    from GUY G join ACTIVITY A on G.ID = A.GUY_ID
    where G.COUNTRY = 'XPTO'
    GROUP BY to_char(A.Date_Act, 'YYYY')
    ) 
where rnk=1;
```

Or ROW_NUMBER instead of RANK if you need only one row.

Comment: This was exacly what I wanted! Big thanks. Thanks for taking some time to answer me.